# Fetch only some keys of PFObject from Parse to save data volume - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, thumbnails

I want to use parse.com for the backend of a social network based on images. To save the data volume of the user I need a way to fetch only some keys from an `PFObject`/row saved in parse.com, because then I would be able to fetch the image saved as a `PFFile` only when the user wants to see it.
Furthermore I wanted to ask if parse.com provides a way to only fetch thumbnails of a image saved in a `PFFile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch only some keys, use `selectKeys:` as documented here:

http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/selectKeys:

To have thumbnails, you'll need to create a 2nd file as described here:

https://parse.com/docs/cloud_modules_guide#images-example